# Sony Camera API - Content URL get request 500, malformed URL?

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

With the latest Sony Camera API, I'm able to get a list of the contents on the memory card. When I'm trying to download the images using a `GET` request, I'm getting a 500 error without any descriptive error messages.

I believe there might be something wrong with the URL I'm using for the get request.

This is the first result part of the JSON response from `getContentList`

```
{   "id" : 12,   "result" : [
    [
      {
        "isPlayable" : "false",
        "content" : {
          "thumbnailUrl" : "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/thumb\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000044-00000AF2_68_1_1000",
          "original" : [
            {
              "stillObject" : "raw",
              "url" : "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/orgraw\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000044-00000AF2_68_1_1000",
              "fileName" : "_DSC7790.ARW"
            }
          ],
          "smallUrl" : "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/vga\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000044-00000AF2_68_1_1000",
          "largeUrl" : "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/scn\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000044-00000AF2_68_1_1000"
        },
        "fileNo" : "7790",
        "isBrowsable" : "false",
        "isProtected" : "",
        "title" : "",
        "contentKind" : "still",
        "createdTime" : "2017-01-12T13:49:00-08:00",
        "folderNo" : "100",
        "uri" : "image:content?contentId=index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000044-00000AF2_68_1_1000"
      },
```

The url is encoded, but when I decode it I'm getting this for the thumbnailUrl:

`http://192.168.122.1:8080/contentstransfer/thumb/index://1000/00000001-default/00000043-00000AF0_67_1_1000`

Of course that is giving me a 500 error, but I believe the characters after thumb must be some URL for the camera to internally parse. So instead I'm just removing the back slashes to get this:

`http://192.168.122.1:8080/contentstransfer/thumb/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000043-00000AF0_67_1_1000`

This still also gives me a 500 error. I'm not sure how else I'm supposed to use this URL. All the API documentation and references just say do a `GET` request, but the URL that comes in the JSON is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I can only spoke for me: I want video-data instead of thumbnail-data and I just used the url as given through their "result" JSON-Object and I got no problems. For me this looks like this:

http://192.168.122.1:8080/contentstransfer/org/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000100-default%2F00000047-00000C3D_71_256_1000